# Webdesign workflow - HTML or CSS first?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been designing website for about a year now (self taught HTML, CSS and JavaScript) but on my last project I experience some designing and code structure issues.

I usually start by laying out my entire website with divs (I add background-color to create boxes to layout the website) and then I start writing the html/content. For the JavaScript, I write it as needed.

I was wondering what's the most efficient way to approach webdesign workflow and avoid extra-work such I experienced on my previous project. Should I start by writing the html, then the CSS and finish with the JavaScript?

Comment: There isn't really a right answer. My personal way is to do all the html with the classes i need then style that. CSS shouldn't dictate the semantics and structure of my page

Comment: Try to write javascript first, and let us know about experience(s)... :)

Comment: Isn't that a bit like building a car by trying to assemble all the plastic bits, then all the metal bits, then all the rubber bits ...

Comment: Your structure is indeed the most important thing, as it focuses on the content. If you ever redesign your site, you only need to change CSS and JS and not the whole thing, so... HTML first. Then CSS, as some people use your site with Javascript disabled. Then javascript - javascript should be icing on the cake, not the main focus.

Comment: There is no one 'best' way to make a website because it is personal preference. But it is always good to plan out beforehand exactly what you plan on putting in the website. (Drawings, mockups, animation sketches). If you don't have much experience with designing websites I would then suggest completely writing up the Html, not simply with divs, but using good Html practices such as this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B73dV.jpg

Then take your time designing the elements in CSS and javascript once you have a full skeleton of Html to work on and mockups to lead your way.

Comment: you shouldn't have to re-write all your css if you change your code, you're doing css wrong if you do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by **Wire Framing** it on Pen and paper, or a whiteboard if available. After that you'll wont have any structures problems anymore.

You can put out a layout that gives you some idea how the project will look and it will catch up a lot of early development/design problems, you then do the HTML and CSS simultaneous. Once you reached the point of a golden door but a not so golden inside. You'll add JS, and change/add some CSS of necessary. Also you should keep a question in mind while doing JS "do i need this or does CSS/HTML do it too".

Comment: I know you can't comment yet but you don't even mention the three things the OP mentions in his question: html, js and css. So... _irrelevant_.

Comment: you're right, i'll make it relevant then.

Comment: @Hammster I would not bother trying to make it relevant as this question wont stay here for much longer. You made a good point and should just leave it at that, I will upvote you to help get ya to the comments quicker.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I concur.

Comment: @Hammster lol as I was writting this it got put on hold.... Told ya.

Comment: @Hammster thanks for the information! Really useful. I am going to dive deeper into **Wire Framing**!